# My javascript clear input code only works if I use this code?

Tags: javascript

Why does my input form only clear my value when I use `e.target.value=""` and not when I use `input=""`?

Here is what my code looks like that works properly

```
create: function (e) {
            var input = e.target.value;
            var val = input.trim();


            if (e.which !== ENTER_KEY || !val) {
                return;
            }

            this.todos.push({
                id: util.uuid(),
                title: val,
                completed: false
            });

            e.target.value="";

            this.render();
        },
```

But when I use this code, it doesn't clear the input field. Everything is the same except the 2nd to last line

```
create: function (e) {
            var input = e.target.value;
            var val = input.trim();


            if (e.which !== ENTER_KEY || !val) {
                return;
            }

            this.todos.push({
                id: util.uuid(),
                title: val,
                completed: false
            });

            input="";

            this.render();
        },
```

When I debugger my code and use `input=""` it just shows exactly that `input=""`, but when I use `e.target.value=""` it actually shows what was clicked and then clears it.

I don't get why `input=""` isn't clearing my input form when my var input = e.target.value??

Comment: `input` is a new variable. its not a reference to the property `value`.

Comment: so the only way I can target my input field is to use e.target.value? or is there an alternative way to write it?

Comment: because it is not a shallow copy of that object when you initialize only the value in your variable.

Comment: You could do `var t = e.target;` and then `t.value = "";` to simplify a litle bit.